# Doctrine2 avoiding SET NAME UTF8

Tags: doctrine-orm

My database and all tables have UTF8 character set. Yet Doctrine2 adds to each connection (i.e. web-page) additional distinct command, as I can see in Symfony2's debugger (showing e.g. all queries to DB):

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

Which is unnecessary. Is it possible to avoid it? How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Doctrine in Symfony2.1 - maybe it helps.

Comment: Do you have your MySQL server set up to skip-character-set-client-handshake? I think some people overlook the fact that even though the server, database and tables can have UTF-8 character sets, the *connection* by the client also has a character set. It's a common solution to run SET NAMES UTF8 to avoid any problems with character sets.

You can check the connection character set with "show variables like 'character_set_client';"